# How to test alexa custom skills on alexa app before publishing?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created sample skill with aws lamda functions. I have tested skills using simulator which is working fine. I want to test skills on alexa app.

Can anybody mention steps to test skills on alexa app from scratch ?

Comment: What are the requirements needed to test custom skills on alexa app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Alexa Skills are **automatically installed** on your device where the registration device is done with the same developer account. Even before you publish a Skill you will find in the section Skill and Games of the app Alexa under the tab your Skill section Developers.

Comment: I found my skill on alexa app,i am always getting " Sorry, i don't that message". But i didn't understand how to register device in developer console ? Do i need to get any alexa enabled device ?

Comment: When you create a skill it's already attached to your developer account. You don't have to do anything else to enable the skill for your account.

Answer (score 1):

Your development skill is available in "Skills > Your Skills" page of the Alexa App. You can enable the skill and test its functionality by asking Alexa, ...

NOTE: - check the language to your skill compiled is same as your Alexa App language.
Make sure your request complies with https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html

Comment: The locale on the device must match the locale of the developed skill. In my case device was English IN, but skill was English US

Answer (score 0):

The developer console should work. You dont need to write 'Alexa tell skillname to do something'. Leave out the 'Alexa' in the beginning. Otherwise you can also the skill directly on a device. When the skill is enabled for testing, and you have an alexa device under the same account, you can already use the skill on that device.

Answer (score 0):

You can test it with Alexa App,

1. Login to Alexa app with your developer account.
2. Click on the Alexa Logo at the bottom center to make Alexa listen to you.
3. Open your skill with your invocation name.

You can also see You skill under `Skills and Games` section of the Alexa app.

1. Open `Skills and Games`
2. Click on `Your Skills` (Top right)
3. Your skill will be listed under `Dev Skills`.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple. Just download the Alexa app on your smartphone and Log in with the same ID that you used to develop the skill. In the "Skills and Games" section, you will find your skill under the "In dev" tab. From there you can test your skill.